# Restsharp get text Files from Server

Tags: c#, request, restsharp

I'm new to Restsharp. I got a client request and in these "Files" are ten text files.

With this request, I want to return all file names shown in my console, but when I run it, the console is still empty and I don't know why...

Maybe someone can help me :)

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:12345/files/");
client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\n\t\"Username\": \"" + username + "\",\n\t\"Password\": \"" + password + "\",\n\t\"DeviceID\": \"Test\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: Personally I would use just a regular HttpClient, restsharp has out lived it usefulness. However that aside, with issues like this you would try and get it to work in Postman first, it can generate restsharp code for you (though its not perfect)

Comment: When i try it in Postman, it works...

Comment: Can you paste the raw request that is working into your question

Comment: The raw Request consists of username, password and DeviceID

Comment: XXX out the sensitive information

Comment: Also I want to download these files and save it local, is it possible with rest or should i use HttpClient?